# Passing data from View to Controller (MVC 3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I've a problem with my ASP.NET application when I try to pass a string from a view to a controller...

*My controller (needed method)*

```
`public ActionResult Mail(int id) //Display the View "Mail"
    {
        Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
        return View(customer);
    }

    [HttpPost,ActionName("Mail")] // this Method allow to send a email
    public ActionResult MailConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
        string message = Request.Form.Get("messageBody");//Here I try to recuperate my messageBody
        if(message!=null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message);
            SendMail(customer.Mail, customer.Name, message);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Veuillez rentrer un message SVP"); 
        }
        return View(customer);
    }`
```

*View "Mail"* (Page where the manager can enter a message body and click on "mail" to send the message)

```
'@using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
   <fieldset>
       <legend>Customer</legend>

       <div class="display-label">Pin</div>
       <div class="display-field">
           @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Pin)
       </div>

       <div class="display-label">Name</div>
       <div class="display-field">
           @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
       </div>

        etc...

       <div class="display-field">
           @Html.TextBox("messageBody",null)//here the value that I try to pass in my controller
       </div>


   </fieldset>
  }
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
 <p>
     <input type="submit" value="Mail" />
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
 </p>
  }`
```

**the "message" is always null...Can you help me, please ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your controller method like this:

```
[HttpPost,ActionName("Mail")] // this Method allow to send a email
    public ActionResult MailConfirmed(int id, string messageBody)
    {
        Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);

        if(messageBody!=null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(messageBody);
            SendMail(customer.Mail, customer.Name, messageBody);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Veuillez rentrer un message SVP"); 
        }
        return View(customer);
    }
```

Also you are passing null from "messageBody" field. Change null to "message is this" and see if it's working.